# Python virtual environments created since mid-August raise `AssertionError` for `python3 -m pip freeze`

Tags: python, pip, virtual-environment, flit

On both MacOS 10.15.7 (Python 3.8.6) and Ubuntu 20.04 (Python 3.8.5), I have installed various virtual environments for various Python scripts I am writing (all in Git and on Github). The projects use `pyproject.toml` for use with `flit`. I created and populated the environments with modules used in the scripts as follows (where $VENVS is the directory where I keep virtual environments):

```
$ python3 -m venv $VENVS/csvenv
$ source $VENVS/csvenv/bin/activate
(csvenv) $ python3 -m pip install --upgrade flit
(csvenv) $ flit install -s      # to install script as "editable"
```

HOWEVER, on both platforms the command `python3 -m pip freeze` gets different results, when executed in a virtual environment:

- In environments created before August 17, it displays the installed modules (as it should).
- In newer environments, I get:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tbaker/venvs/dcapenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 228, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/tbaker/venvs/dcapenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py", line 101, in run
    for line in freeze(**freeze_kwargs):
  File "/Users/tbaker/venvs/dcapenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py", line 67, in freeze
    req = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist)
  File "/Users/tbaker/venvs/dcapenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py", line 257, in from_dist
    req = direct_url_as_pep440_direct_reference(
  File "/Users/tbaker/venvs/dcapenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/direct_url_helpers.py", line 49, in direct_url_as_pep440_direct_reference
    assert not direct_url.info.editable
AssertionError
```

My guess that this depends on when an environment was created is based both on directory timestamps and on examination of builds on Readthedocs, which rebuilds documentation whenever a repo is pushed.

Documentation for a project with an environment created before August 17 has continued to rebuild without interruption, while the documentation for a project with the newer environment has failed to build since August. With the August 17 commit, a `requirements.txt` file was added.

If I restore that `requirements.txt`, the RTD build fails with this message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv2shex==0.2 (from -r docs/requirements.txt (line 16)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for csv2shex==0.2 (from -r docs/requirements.txt (line 16))
```

If I exit the virtual environment with `deactivate`, execute  `python3 -m pip freeze >requirements.txt` (which works outside of the virtual environment) and push, Readthedocs fails to build with the same error.

`pip freeze >requirements.txt` does work when I use a virtual environment created in July. However, when I clone that project on Ubuntu and re-create a virtual environment (as above), `pip freeze` raises the exception. It also fails if I create and populate a new virtual environment for that on MacOS. However, if I create a new `requirements.txt` file within the virtual environment from July, and push, the documentation builds.

The exception is raised at line 49 of pip's [direct_url_helpers.py](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/utils/direct_url_helpers.py), which includes the following comment:

```
    # pip should never reach this point for editables, since
    # pip freeze inspects the editable project location to produce
    # the requirement string
    assert not direct_url.info.editable
```

I have researched this for many hours. Searches on `pip freeze`, `AssertionError`, `editable project location`, and the like have turned up nothing. The [Stackoverflow search "pip freeze assertionerror"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pip+freeze+assertionerror) yields just 12 results, all but one from 2015, or before, plus one from 2019 about an issue involving Docker.

To summarize, it appears to me that:

- On my MacOS and Ubuntu systems, `pip freeze` does not work in virtual environments created since August 17 (using `python3 -m venv`)
- Readthedocs documentation builds succeed in the presence of a `requirements.txt` file built using a virtual environment older than August 17.
- Readthedocs documentation builds fail in the presence of a `requirements.txt` file built outside of any virtual environment -- always with the message above, which refers to

However, some things do not add up:

- I am fairly sure I would have created the `requirements.txt` file of August 17 from within the virtual environment because I never work with projects outside of the virtual environment. But how can that be unless `pip freeze` were working?

Can anyone out there explain? Is this a problem with `python3 -m venv`, `flit`, or something else? Am I at least correct to suspect that the failures of the RTD builds are somehow related to the failures of `pip freeze`?

Comment: What versions of Python, pip, flit, and any other tools for each venv? Specifically, are there differences between those that work and those that don't? Of course, as `pip freeze` is not working, you will need to get the versions from the individual tools. For example, after activating an env,  use `pip --version`, `python --version`, `flit --version`, etc.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but there was [a change to `pip freeze` merged on April 1 2020](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/7612) that includes the `AssertionError` you describe here. That thread on github might be useful. Apparently that pull request is an implementation of [PEP 610](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0610/).

Comment: The change mentioned by @jakub was [included](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7951) in pip version 20.1. My guess is that your older venvs have an older version of pip installed and the venvs created later are all using version 20.1 or later,

Comment: @Waylan Thank you for the suggestion. The virtual environment created July, in which `pip freeze` works, has Flit 2.3.0 and Pip 20.2.3 with Python 3.8. The newer venv, in which `pip freeze` does NOT work, has Flit 3.0.0 and Pip 20.2.3 with Python 3.8.

Comment: I have created an issue on the Pip repo describing exactly [how to reproduce this problem](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8996).

Comment: I raised an [issue on Flit](https://github.com/takluyver/flit/issues/372) in case the problem lies in a difference between Flit 2.3.0 and 3.0.0. A [response re: Pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8996#issuecomment-708212621) already that it may have to do with a "combination of flit generating the editable flag in direct_url.json (which is correct) and pip being confused because flit's notion of editable is not recognized by pip."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure of `pip freeze` was indeed a bug in Pip 2.2. This bug has [already been fixed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8996) for the upcoming Pip 2.3.